# GORM. Не получается вставить вложенную структуру в БД. duplicate key

Tags: postgresql, golang

Мне не удалось построить минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Проблема следующая. Есть что-то в духе:

```
type Project struct {
  ID                int                  `json:"id"`
}

type Content struct {

  ProjectID        int                         `json:"project_id"`
  Project          database.Project            `json:"-"` 

}

func (c Content) TableName() string {
  return "content"
}

func (c Project) TableName() string {
  return "project"
}
```

Я заполняю поля. И получаю кикуш:

```
database.AP.Debug().Save(src)
```

`src` — как Content. В итоге,

> pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "project_pkey"

Миграции:

```
create table project (
    id serial not null constraint project_pkey primary key,
);


create table content (
    id bigserial not null constraint content_pkey primary key,
    project_id bigint constraint content_project_id_fkey references project,
);
```

Лог:

```
(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.84ms]  UPDATE "project" SET "type" = 'VIDEO_PROTECTION', "status" = 'new', "orig_title" = 'c8a57bd778bd402fb5eb84d4f31ef341', "rus_title" = 'de0a202bd4b649a290c94d2461d41379', "owner_id" = 112113385, "curator_id" = 709640095, "begin_protection_at" = '1983-09-09 18:56:55', "end_protection_at" = '2022-08-15 16:05:15', "claim_title" = '3ecc4a53890a40ccb7609cd7195080c7', "procuration_num" = '70ce096271654ea4b8df4dd86ab6cc2a', "procuration_link" = 'b4367efc229442e6bd8b20cea5e91b56', "rightholder" = 'a5a3c0fdd10844b0915a930fa4eeafee', "claim_email" = 'cba2354ad8c84dc58d4af3769dd39624', "uuid" = 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff', "agent_name" = '37f1b28568934d85ac1acfe5d8079edc', "agent_position" = 'e8a217fbcb78462fa53bdd77137135d5', "claim_agent" = '830aa8cb4b0d4fbc9f49027335e73a97', "fp2_uuid" = 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff', "check_period" = 558903663, "min_content_length" = '2562047h47m16.854775807s', "created_at" = '2018-07-23 03:02:33', "updated_at" = '2021-01-20 20:50:39', "deleted_at" = '1999-03-20 16:11:43'  WHERE "project"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "project"."id" = 107595726  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.58ms]  SELECT * FROM "project"  WHERE "project"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "project"."id" = 107595726 ORDER BY "project"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.86ms]  INSERT INTO "project" ("id","type","status","orig_title","rus_title","owner_id","curator_id","begin_protection_at","end_protection_at","claim_title","procuration_num","procuration_link","rightholder","claim_email","uuid","agent_name","agent_position","claim_agent","fp2_uuid","check_period","min_content_length","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at") VALUES (107595726,'VIDEO_PROTECTION','new','c8a57bd778bd402fb5eb84d4f31ef341','de0a202bd4b649a290c94d2461d41379',112113385,709640095,'1983-09-09 18:56:55','2022-08-15 16:05:15','3ecc4a53890a40ccb7609cd7195080c7','70ce096271654ea4b8df4dd86ab6cc2a','b4367efc229442e6bd8b20cea5e91b56','a5a3c0fdd10844b0915a930fa4eeafee','cba2354ad8c84dc58d4af3769dd39624','f9a02262-e58b-4f9a-bfb4-52bc5c98876f','37f1b28568934d85ac1acfe5d8079edc','e8a217fbcb78462fa53bdd77137135d5','830aa8cb4b0d4fbc9f49027335e73a97','c2c900b6-8117-42f6-9380-ba067dc8b4aa',558903663,'2562047h47m16.854775807s','2018-07-23 03:02:33','2021-01-20 20:50:39','1999-03-20 16:11:43') RETURNING "project"."id"  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.81ms]  UPDATE "content" SET "uid" = 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff', "project_id" = 107595726, "url" = '74a55eb33b664a7f9d9f7eb8ef409efe', "hash" = '757bddf58e7d4665b9524bd2f4f55fdc', "type" = 'FILE', "duration" = '378.913792ms', "manual_match" = 'FOUND', "auto_match" = 'ERROR', "manual_matched_at" = '1979-03-06 16:18:41', "system_matched_at" = '2009-02-09 12:23:59', "matched_by" = NULL, "source" = '55fd9f5d6fcd423a941811254dc6c9c9', "tmp_direct_source" = '922b004f87ff419b881a6338563908dc', "download_status" = 'NEW', "check_status" = 'NEED_RECHECK', "error_description" = 'c75594af60da42bd939690e3f7371e56', "last_resource_id" = 348626383, "created_at" = '1970-04-23 16:33:24', "updated_at" = '2021-01-20 20:50:39', "deleted_at" = '2013-07-25 00:09:22'  WHERE "content"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "content"."id" = 677899544  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.62ms]  SELECT * FROM "content"  WHERE "content"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "content"."id" = 677899544 ORDER BY "content"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.53ms]  UPDATE "project" SET "type" = 'VIDEO_PROTECTION', "status" = 'new', "orig_title" = 'c8a57bd778bd402fb5eb84d4f31ef341', "rus_title" = 'de0a202bd4b649a290c94d2461d41379', "owner_id" = 112113385, "curator_id" = 709640095, "begin_protection_at" = '1983-09-09 18:56:55', "end_protection_at" = '2022-08-15 16:05:15', "claim_title" = '3ecc4a53890a40ccb7609cd7195080c7', "procuration_num" = '70ce096271654ea4b8df4dd86ab6cc2a', "procuration_link" = 'b4367efc229442e6bd8b20cea5e91b56', "rightholder" = 'a5a3c0fdd10844b0915a930fa4eeafee', "claim_email" = 'cba2354ad8c84dc58d4af3769dd39624', "uuid" = 'f9a02262-e58b-4f9a-bfb4-52bc5c98876f', "agent_name" = '37f1b28568934d85ac1acfe5d8079edc', "agent_position" = 'e8a217fbcb78462fa53bdd77137135d5', "claim_agent" = '830aa8cb4b0d4fbc9f49027335e73a97', "fp2_uuid" = 'c2c900b6-8117-42f6-9380-ba067dc8b4aa', "check_period" = 558903663, "min_content_length" = '2562047h47m16.854775807s', "created_at" = '2018-07-23 03:02:33', "updated_at" = '2021-01-20 20:50:39', "deleted_at" = '1999-03-20 16:11:43'  WHERE "project"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "project"."id" = 107595726  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.63ms]  SELECT * FROM "project"  WHERE "project"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "project"."id" = 107595726 ORDER BY "project"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "project_pkey" 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  [0.76ms]  INSERT INTO "project" ("id","type","status","orig_title","rus_title","owner_id","curator_id","begin_protection_at","end_protection_at","claim_title","procuration_num","procuration_link","rightholder","claim_email","uuid","agent_name","agent_position","claim_agent","fp2_uuid","check_period","min_content_length","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at") VALUES (107595726,'VIDEO_PROTECTION','new','c8a57bd778bd402fb5eb84d4f31ef341','de0a202bd4b649a290c94d2461d41379',112113385,709640095,'1983-09-09 18:56:55','2022-08-15 16:05:15','3ecc4a53890a40ccb7609cd7195080c7','70ce096271654ea4b8df4dd86ab6cc2a','b4367efc229442e6bd8b20cea5e91b56','a5a3c0fdd10844b0915a930fa4eeafee','cba2354ad8c84dc58d4af3769dd39624','e0b23b88-06b3-4713-9ef8-5978b830738a','37f1b28568934d85ac1acfe5d8079edc','e8a217fbcb78462fa53bdd77137135d5','830aa8cb4b0d4fbc9f49027335e73a97','ee410865-583d-4bb4-a7b5-071ee8179ca5',558903663,'2562047h47m16.854775807s','2018-07-23 03:02:33','2021-01-20 20:50:39','1999-03-20 16:11:43') RETURNING "project"."id"  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/user/go/src/***/ap/database/pkg/content.go:51) 
[2021-01-20 20:50:39]  pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "project_pkey"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, некорректно пользоваться при вставке [`Save`](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html). `Save` используется для `UPDATE`. При этом в документации есть примеры, которые используются для вставки. Это странно. О том, что использовать `Save` для вставки нельзя или это приводит к побочным эффектам, я ничего не увидел в документации. Для вставки нужно пользоваться [`Create`](https://gorm.io/docs/create.htm).

Если использовать `Save` для вложенных структур, тогда согласно логу происходит следующее:

1. Сначала идёт обновление внутренних структур.
2. Затем обновляется `Content` и ещё раз обновляются внутренние структуры

Это происходит из-за двухэтапного обновления:

1. Вызов `callbacks`.
2. Вызов основного метода обновления.

На этапе `callbacks` вызываются все методы для поиска, вставки вложенных структур и обновления `Content`. На этапе основного метода, вызывается метод для вставки `Content` и ещё раз для вставки `Project`. Вот так выглядит реализация метода `Save`:

```
// Save update value in database, if the value doesn't have primary key, will insert it
func (s *DB) Save(value interface{}) *DB {
    scope := s.NewScope(value)
    if !scope.PrimaryKeyZero() {
        newDB := scope.callCallbacks(s.parent.callbacks.updates).db // Этап 1
        if newDB.Error == nil && newDB.RowsAffected == 0 {
            return s.New().Table(scope.TableName()).FirstOrCreate(value) // Этап 2
        }
        return newDB
    }
    return scope.callCallbacks(s.parent.callbacks.creates).db
}
```